# Add a Linq method to an Expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am trying to make a generic method that takes an expression and add method call to this expression.
Like for example I want to add .Contains or .StartsWith linq methods to the expression.

Here is a simple code to show what I am trying to do.

```
string filter = "startsWith";
Expression<Func<LogRequest,bool>> exp;
exp = log => log.Message;
MyFunction(exp, filter, "My Message");
exp = log => log.ClientIP;
MyFunction(exp, filter, "192.168");

public void MyFunction(Expression<Func<LogRequest,bool>> exp, string filter, string message)
{
  switch (filter)
  {
      case "StartsWith":
          {
              exp = exp.AndAlso(exp.StartsWith(message));
              break;
          }
      case "Contains":
          {
              exp = exp.AndAlso(exp.Contains(message));
              break;
          }
}
```

and here is the AndAlso function, it's an Expression extension method

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AndAlso<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> left, Expression<Func<T, bool>> right)
        {
            var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(right, left.Parameters);
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(left.Body, invokedExpr), left.Parameters);
        }
```

I want to do this because I have more than 15 Property in the LogRequest class that will use the same logic and I don't want to break the DRY principle.

So the expected value of the Expression exp after this should be

```
exp = log => log.Message.StartsWith("My Message") && log.ClientIP.StartsWith("192.168");
```

Comment: Comments generally end with question marks and there doesn't appear to be one in your OP. What isn't working for you? What is? What exactly is your question?

Comment: @ClearlyClueless I am trying to make something like the code i provided. But this code is just an explaination for what i want to do not an actual code.

Comment: Understandable, however there are no questions being asked here and stackoverflow is specifically for asking questions.